# Putting multiple javascript values into table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a script that puts an array of links into 1 frame, and checks their loadtime:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
var array = ['http://www.example1.come', 'http://www.example2.com', 'http://www.example3.com'];
var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();
var loadTimes = [];
$('#1').on('load', function() {
   loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime());                  
   $('#1').attr('src', array.pop());
    if (array.length === 0) { 
        $.each(loadTimes, function(index, value) {
           alert(value - beforeLoad); 
        });
    }
}).attr('src', array.pop());
});
</script>
```

I would like to put all values into a table instead of alerting them. I mean put them in here (creates 3x td's and puts loadingtime values in each):

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <?php for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++){ ?>
    <td id="loadingtime<?php echo $i; ?>">  
    <?php  } ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP loop is a little broken. But that's ok because it is unnecessary - just draw out the 3 TDs.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="loadingtime1">  
        </td>
        <td id="loadingtime2">  
        </td>
        <td id="loadingtime3">  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The short way to add javascript variables to a table is NOT through PHP. You can add them directly using `$.().html`.

Instead of `alert(value - beforeLoad);`

Use: `$("#loadingtime"+index).html(value - beforeLoad);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in jquery not php.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var array = ['http://www.example1.come', 'http://www.example2.com', 
                 'http://www.example3.com'];
    var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();
    var loadTimes = [];
    $('#1').on('load', function() {
       loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime());                  
       $('#1').attr('src', array.pop());
        if (array.length === 0) {
            var table = $('<table><tr></tr></table>');
            var tr = table.find('tr');
            $.each(loadTimes, function(index, value) {
               tr.append('<td>' + (value - beforeLoad) + '</td>');
            });
            table.appendTo('body');
        }
    }).attr('src', array.pop());

});
```